# Still about quote in Lisp

Tags: lisp, quote

I am a novice in Lisp, learning slowly at spare time... Months ago, I was puzzled by the error report from a Lisp REPL that the following expression does not work:

`((if (> 2 1) + -) 1 2)`

By looking around then I knew that Lisp is not Scheme...in Lisp, I need to do either:

`(funcall (if (> 2 1) '+ '-)  2 1)`,  or

`(funcall (if (> 2 1) #'+ #'-)  2 1)`

I also took a glimpse of introductary material about lisp-1 and lisp-2, although I was not able to absort the whole stuff there...in any case, I knew that `quote` prevents evaluation, as an exception to the evaluation rule.

Recently I am reading something about `reduce`...and then as an exercise, I wanted to write my own version of reduce. Although I managed to get it work (at least it seems working), I realized that I still cannot exactly explain why, in the body of `defun`, that some places `funcall` is needed, and at some places not.

The following is `myreduce` in elisp:

```
    (defun myreduce (fn v lst)
    (cond ((null lst) v)
          ((atom lst) (funcall fn v lst))
          (t (funcall fn (car lst) (myreduce fn v (cdr lst))))))

(myreduce '+ 0 '(1 2 3 4))
```

My questions are about the 3rd and 4th lines:

1. The 3rd line: why I need `funcall`? why not just `(fn v lst)`? My "argument" is that in `(fn v lst)`, `fn` is the first element in the list, so lisp may be able to use this position information to treat it as a function...but it's not. So certainly I missed something here.
2. The 4th line in the recursive call of `myreduce`: what kind of `fn` be passed to the recursive call to `myreduce`? `'+` or `+`, or something else?

I guess there should be something very fundamental I am not aware of...I wanted to know, when I call `myreduce` as shown in the 6th/last line, what is exactly happening afterwards (at least on how the `'+` is passed around), and is there a way to trace that in any REPL environment?

Thanks a lot,

/bruin

Comment: For tracing use `TRACE`.

Answer (score 4):

Common Lisp is a LISP-2 and has two namespaces. One for functions and one for variables. Arguments are bound in the variable namespace so `fn` does not exist in the function namespace.

```
(fn arg) ; call what fn is in the function namespace
(funcall fn ...) ; call a function referenced as a variable
```

`'+` is a symbol and `funcall` and `apply` will look it up in the global function namespace when it sees it's a symbol instead of a function object. `#'+` is an abbreviation for  `(function +)` which resolves the function from the local function namespace. With lots of calls `#'+` is faster than `'+` since `'+` needs a lookup. Both symbol and a function can be passed as `fn` to myreduce and whatever was passed is the same that gets passed in line 4.

```
(myreduce '+ 0 '(1 2 3 4)) ; here funcall might lookup what '+ is every time (CLISP does it while SBLC caches it)
(myreduce #'+ 0 '(1 2 3 4)); here funcall will be given a function object looked up in the first call in all consecutive calls
```

Now if you pass `'+` it will be evaluated to `+` and bound to fn. 
In `myreduce` we pass `fn` in the recursion and it will be evaluated to `+` too.

For `#'+` it evaluates to the function and bound to `fn`.
In `myreduce` we pass `fn` in the recursion and it will be evaluated to the function object `fn` was bound to in the variable namespace.

Common Lisp has construct to add to the function namespace. Eg.

```
(flet ((double (x) (+ x x))) ; make double in the function namespace
  (double 10)) ; ==> 20
```

But you could have written it and used it on the variable namespace:

```
(let ((double #'(lambda (x) (+ x x)))) ; make double in the variable namespace
  (funcall double 10))
```

Comment: What is the justification for the claim that in `"(reduce '+ 0 '(1 2 3 4))` "funcall will lookup what '+ is every time"?  Why couldn't `reduce` be implemented as `(defun reduce (fn-designator ...) (let ((fn (designated-function fn-designator))) ...only use fn, not fn-designator...))`?  I'd actually kind of _expect_ an implementation to only lookup the designated function _once_, and to cache the result (but I'm not claiming that this is, in fact, what happens).

Comment: I just had a look at the SBCL source, and it doesn't look like this optimization is made, but I can't see where it'd be prohibited by the spec., either…

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor It wasn't `reduce` but `myreduce` from OP. Also, it's possible to make `reduce` fix the passed function in case it's `symbolp`, but that may break the programmers intent. Perhaps the function self-mutates? It's a lot easier to let the programmer choose to add one char and send `#'+` or perhaps `(symbol-function '+)` to get the global definition.

Comment: If it's possible, then the programmer who intended that changing the function definition of a symbol during iteration would have a particular behavior is depending on some undefined behavior that future implementation optimizations would probably break.  I'd blame the programmer. :)

Comment: The spec usually talks about these functions (`map[,car,can.…]`, `apply`, `reduce`, etc.) that take function designators in language that says the function designator designates _a_ function, and that _the_ function is called, and so on.  The (implicit) assumption that a function designator designates a single function is broken if a programmer depends on changing the symbol function of a symbol used as a function designator during iteration.

Comment: Actually, while the code I looked at didn't appear to be doing caching, it appears that there must be something in between that does.  E.g., see [this code](http://pastebin.com/DMEeHUSB) and output from SBCL.  The function is clearly being cached in both `mapcar` and `reduce`.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Nice example. CLIST on the other hand. does not cache with `map`/`reduce`. It seems we cannot predict how it will work since, unlike `funcall`, the spec doesn't say when a symbol is coerced to a function so it will be like TCO; implementation dependent.

Comment: OK, [1.4.1.5 Designators](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/01_dae.htm) says: "Except as otherwise noted, in a situation where the denoted object might be used multiple times, it is implementation-dependent whether the object is coerced only once or whether the coercion occurs each time the object must be used.

For example, mapcar receives a function designator as an argument, and its description is written as if this were simply a function. In fact, it is implementation-dependent whether the function designator is coerced right away or whether it is carried around…

Comment: …internally in the form that it was given as an argument and re-coerced each time it is needed. In most cases, conforming programs cannot detect the distinction, but there are some pathological situations (particularly those involving self-redefining or mutually-redefining functions) which do conform and which can detect this difference."  The page goes on to show an example where a function `add-some` redefines itself, and that `(mapcar 'add-some '(1 2 3 4))` could return different results, depending on whether the function is cached or not.

Comment: At any rate, the point was to settle whether the comment in `(myreduce '+ 0 '(1 2 3 4)) ; here funcall will lookup what '+ is every time` is accurate or not.  The spec says that an implementation has the option of looking it up each time, and the option of looking it up just once.  At least one implementation (SBCL) looks it up just once, and caches the value.  So while `funcall will lookup what '+ is every time` might be true in _some_ implementations, it's not true in general of Common Lisp.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor This is very interesting.. I though the SBCL caching only applied to CL higher order functions, but actualy it does this in `myreduce` too.. Even if `myreduce` logically pass only a symbol over to the next iteration. I'll change *will* to *might*, but that CLISP doesn't cache means you cannot depend on it.

Comment: Yeah, I spent more time on this that I really meant to, but it _is_ one of those interesting edge cases that are sort of fun to know about.

Answer (score 2):

Common Lisp has two (actually more than two) namespaces: one for variables and one for functions. This means that one name can mean different things depending on the context: it can be a variable and it can be a function name.

```
(let ((foo 42))    ; a variable FOO
  (flet ((foo (n) (+ n 107)))   ; a function FOO
    (foo foo)))    ; calling function FOO with the value of the variable FOO
```

Some examples how variables are defined:

```
(defun foo (n) ...)   ; n is a variable
(let ((n 3)) ...)     ; n is a variable
(defparameter *n* 41) ; *n* is a variable
```

So whenever a variable is defined and used, the name is in the variable namespace.

Functions are defined:

```
 (defun foo (n) ...)         ; FOO is a function
 (flet ((foo (n) ...)) ...)  ; FOO is a function
```

So whenever a function is defined and used, the name is in the function namespace.

Since the function itself is an object, you can have function being a variable value. If you want to call such a value, then you need to use FUNCALL or APPLY.

```
  (let ((plus (function plus)))
    (funcall plus 10 11))
```

Now why are things like they are? ;-)

- two namespaces allow us to use names as variables which are already functions.

Example: in a Lisp-1 I can't write:

```
(defun list-me (list) (list list))
```

In Common Lisp there is no conflict for above code.

- a separate function namespace makes compiled code a bit simpler:

In a call `(foo 42)` the name FOO can only be undefined or it is a function. Another alternative does not exist. So at runtime we never have to check the function value of FOO for actually being a function object. If FOO has a function value, then it must be a function object. The reason for that: it is not possible in Common Lisp to define a function with something other than a function.

In Scheme you can write:

```
(let ((list 42))
  (list 1 2 3 list))
```

Above needs to be checked at some point and will result in an error, since LIST is 42, which is not a function.

In Common Lisp above code defines only a variable LIST, but the function LIST is still available.